# Add a menthod where if the current day is Monday and we add 4 dates, the day to be returned is Friday

Tags: python

How do I add the method in my title to my code? I'm just going to repeat it from Monday to Sunday. I'm really clueless at the moment please help. :(

```
class DayOfTheWeek(str):
monday = 'Monday'
tuesday = 'Tuesday'
wednesday = 'Wednesday'
thursday = 'Thursday'
friday = 'Friday'
saturday = 'Saturday'
sunday = 'Sunday'

day = str(input("What day is it? "))
if day == 'Monday':
    print("Today is Monday")
    print("Next day will be: "+ tuesday)
    print("Previous day will be: "+ sunday)
```

Comment: make your variables into a dictionary with weekday and numbers

Comment: map day and day no, then do calcluations

Comment: what code do I use in order to put all the numbers into 1 variable?